# Trying to subtract a day or add a day to a pine script timestamp

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

In pine script I have an `input.time()`. I am trying to change the background color one day before, the day of and several days after to different colors. I am doing this to highlight days where an event happened in a list of tickers.
I have tried  to use:

```
starttime   = input.time(timestamp("01 Nov 2021 00:00"), "Start Time") 
prerange    = time <= starttime and time_close[2] >= starttime
bgcolor(prerange ? #0000FF : na)
```

I have gotten it to work between two timestamps but found no way to simply add or subtract a day from a timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

Timestamps are in unix time which is in milliseconds (since Jan 1st 1970).

One day in milliseconds is 86400000ms. We can use this value to add/subtract from the timestamp.

```
starttime   = input.time(timestamp("01 Nov 2021 00:00"), "Start Time") 
event_days  = input.int(2)
post_days   = input.int(5)

pre_ts = starttime - 86400000
post_start_ts = starttime + 86400000 * event_days
post_end_ts = starttime + 86400000 * (event_days + post_days)

pre_range = time >= pre_ts and time < starttime
post_range = time >= post_start_ts and time < post_end_ts

bgcolor(pre_range ? #0000FF : na)
bgcolor(post_range ? #00FF00 : na)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. I am still learning and this helped a lot.